# Android Development Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I have created a search view that takes input. If the input string is greater than or equal to 3 then a drop down is shown with some suggestion. That suggestion list comes from the server, but currently it shows for length 3, but I can't type more in textfield after 3 chars - the keyboard hides if try to write more.

Here is my code snippet.

```
val searchitems by viewmodel.stateFlowMessage.collectAsState()

    var showdropdown by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(56.dp)
            .background(Color.White), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Column() {
                TextField(
                    value = state.value,
                    onValueChange = {
                        state.value = it
                        if (state.value.text.length >= 3) {
                            searchquery()showdropdown = true
                        }

                        
                    },
                    singleLine = true,
                    textStyle = TextStyle(
                        fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                        color = Color.Black,
                        fontSize = 14.sp,
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .fillMaxWidth(1f),
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(
                            text = label,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .wrapContentSize()
                                .padding(start = 15.dp),
                            style = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 14.sp, color = colorResource(id = R.color.grey))
                        )
                    },
                   keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                       imeAction = ImeAction.Search,
                        autoCorrect = true,
                    ),
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Image(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                            contentDescription = "",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(24.dp)
                                .padding(start = 4.dp),
                            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(color = colorResource(id = R.color.grey))
                        )
                    },
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        cursorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.grey),
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                        backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.col2)
                    )
                )
            }
            DropdownMenu(expanded = showdropdown,
                onDismissRequest = { showdropdown = false }, properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false)) {
                Log.d("checks", "${searchitems.size}")
                for (it in searchitems) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        selectitem(it)
                        state.value = TextFieldValue(it)
                        showdropdown = false
                    }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = it,
                            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 14.sp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight(400)))
                    }
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: I run your code, stripping off the parts that I don't know what they do,  its working fine,  but you said the `keyboard hides if you tried to input more`, you have a `searchquery()` function call inside of your `if` block, it could be the reason why your code isn't working

Comment: @z.y it will bring list items for drop down . By the way it gets solved now.